# return a string inside a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, variables

> **Task Instructions**
> In this activity, you will define a variable within a JavaScript function. You'll learn more about functions later. For now, we'll focus on variables.
>
> To accomplish this task, you need to do the following:
>
> - Open the `Variables-01` folder and add code to the `variables01.js` file to do the following:
> - Create a variable called `myFriend` using one of the variable declarations described above.
> - Set the variable you created to contain your friend's name.
> - Inside the `greetings` function, return the string: "Greetings [your-friend's-name]."

I have no idea what I am missing in this code but it still comes up as wrong.

```
/*Instructions
 - Greet your friend by printing a message to the console.
*/
function greetings(greetings ,{myFriend}) {
  var myFriend = 'Mike';
  `greetings ${myFriend}`;
  console.log(myFriend);
  

}

//leave this line unchanged to console log the results
console.log('results: ', greetings());

//don't change this line
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = greetings;
}
```

Comment: Put `return` in front of `\`greetings`?

Comment: Return the template literal AFTER logging to the console.

Comment: The instructions tell you exactly what you need to do: *Inside the greetings function, **return** the string:*

Comment: You could also just make it `function greetings(){` as you are not using the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You need a return statement:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp

ex.

```
/*Instructions
 - Greet your friend by printing a message to the console.
*/
function greetings() {
  var myFriend = 'Mike';
  console.log(myFriend);
  return `greetings ${myFriend}`;
}

//leave this line unchanged to console log the results
console.log('results: ', greetings());

//don't change this line
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = greetings;
}
```

Comment: If it's automarking, make sure it matches exactly: capitalize "greetings" and add a period at the end.

Comment: It says 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'myFriend' of undefined'

Comment: See my edit. You don't need arguments on the greetings() function. The error occurs because of the {myFriend} you had as an argument for greetings()

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with the code:

- The function greetings does not return a value
- You use console.log multiple times, but you could log the return value of the function a single time
- The function arguments `greetings(greetings ,{myFriend})` are not used

If you want to write a function without an explicit return statement, you could shorten the code using a single parameter `myFriend` with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
const greetings = myFriend => `greetings ${myFriend}`;
console.log('results: ', greetings("Mike"));

if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = greetings;
}
```

```js
const greetings = myFriend => `greetings ${myFriend}`;
console.log('results: ', greetings("Mike"));
```